# How to write an IF THEN ELSE statement for the value inside of a text box?

Tags: excel, vba

I can't figure out how to write the code so it bases the statement off of the numerical value inside of my text box. Writing it as `TextBox1.Value` is not working. No matter what number I put into the text box the "50" from the `Else` line is the only part that works.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    If TextBox1.Value < 5 Then
        Label1 = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(((WorksheetFunction.Power(TextBox1, 3)) * _
        0.32) * Cells(1, 20), 0)
    ElseIf TextBox1.Value > 5 Then
        Label1 = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(((WorksheetFunction.Power(TextBox1, 3)) * _
        0.29) * Cells(1, 20), 0)
    Else
        Label1 = "50"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: `TextBox1.Text` ? Did you try that ? Though `.Value` should work

Comment: What do you mean by not working? What do you expect and what is actually happening?

Comment: Just after the line `Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()`, Type this line `Label1.Caption=""`. Now check

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the Functions. Your Code is running fine otherwise

Comment: @SiddharthRout What I need is for the value in TextBox1 to determine the number that is plugged into a formula. If the number is less than 5 it plugs in 0.32, if the number is greater than or equal to 5 it plugs in 0.29.

Comment: @AlexDavie .. Can you explain how your formula is working ?

Comment: @SiddharthRout It still shows 50 with that suggestion.

Comment: Ok few questions. **1.** What is the value of cell `Cells(1, 20)` **2.** What value are you typing in the textbox? **3.** What output are you expecting? **4.** What output are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer, but it's a good way to start debugging your issue, and too long to comment. Something must be off with the value you think you have, so here's some code that can help you debug it.

Also, you might want to make sure the Cells reference is to the respective worksheet. I've included that below too...

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
    Dim confirmNumber As Double

    If IsNumeric(textbox1.Value) Then
        confirmNumber = textbox1.Value

        MsgBox "the value is " & confirmNumber

        MsgBox "the value in cell T1 is " & Me.Cells(1, 20).Value
        Stop
    Else
        MsgBox textbox1.Value & " is not a number"
        'make some changes to make it a number?
        confirmNumber = CDbl(textbox1.Value)
        Stop
    End If

'
'    If confirmNumber < 5 Then
'        Label1 = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(((WorksheetFunction.Power(textbox1, 3)) * 0.32) * me.Cells(1, 20), 0)
'    ElseIf confirmNumber > 5 Then
'        Label1 = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(((WorksheetFunction.Power(textbox1, 3)) * 0.29) * me.Cells(1, 20), 0)
'    Else
'        Label1 = "50"
'    End If

End Sub
```